# Song that plays during episodes previews of Hunter x Hunter

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

What is the song that plays during episodes previews of Hunter x Hunter? I have had zero luck finding the name of this song and I've looked through playlists.

I know some songs haven't been released and I just hope this one is out there but I'm just bad at looking for it

Answer (score 1):

According to Glass Reflection's review ( https://youtu.be/VgnSAOSo-Tk?t=10m22s ) and a re-listen to the preview music, it is called *The World of Adventures,* by Yoshihisa Hirano. I found the whole track: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOBppjlkXGc